# Define token for single call without app id+secret with Facebook SDK 4, Graph API 2.X

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

With the previous graph api and facebook's SDK, I could define a single token as

```
'access_token => $token'
```

and that's it.

But now, with the new SDK, I don't know how to do it and if it's even possible.

This is my new code (which doesn't work):

```
<?php

require_once 'autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;


$request = new FacebookRequest(
$session,
  'POST',
  '/post_id/comments',
  array (
'access_token' => 'CAALXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'message' => 'this is a test',
  )
);

?>
```

(Of course when i'm running the code i'm changing the values of the access token & post id)

And this is my previous code which works:

```
<?php

require_once('dir/src/facebook.php');


  $config = array(
    'fileUpload' => true,
    'allowSignedRequest' => false
  );

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

$comment = $facebook->api('/post_id/comments', 'POST', array(
'access_token' => 'CASDASDASDASDASDASDSDSD',
'message' => 'this is a test message',
)
);


?>
```

The error which is being shown is:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Facebook\FacebookRequest::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\FacebookSession, string given, called in /home//public_html/post_comment.php on line 27 and defined in /home/public_html/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php on line 187

Please help me to understand how to comment with a single token without the need to login to any app through facebook's new sdk.

Thanks alot.

Comment: You don't set `$session` to anything

Comment: because I don't want any session to be started or any authorization with my app or something.. I want to define the "session" or the token beforehand as something that already defined like this specific token.

Comment: Then create `$session` from the accesstoken. By doing `$session = new FacebookSession($accesstoken);`

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I'v tried in every way which is possible. I replaced the $accesstoken with the actual token in " " & ' ' , still won't work.

Comment: And it's wierd, because in facebook's docs they explain to do exactly what you've told me, and that's still not working. Is there any way to use sdk 4 without defining app id & app secret and just run my token?

Comment: What error do you get when you do what I said?

Comment: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'You must provide or set a default application secret.' in /home/public_html/a/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php:340 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/a/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(295): Facebook\FacebookSession::_getTargetAppSecret() #1 /home/public_html/a/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php(209): Facebook\FacebookRequest->getAppSecretProof('CAALZCTBwxuOQBA...') #2 /home/public_html/a/post_comment.php(26):

Comment: Do you have app secret proof enabled? If so, disable it and try again with new FacebookSession($accesstoken); and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set up a new Facebook application [which you can find here](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/).

Follow the prompts and save the App ID and App Secret.

Start a session:

```
session_start();
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$secret);
FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);
```

But now you want an access token, so let's request one (so we don't have to manually get one every time it expires):

```
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();
$response = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/oauth/access_token?client_id='.($app_id.'&client_secret='.$secret.'&grant_type=client_credentials'))->execute();
$token = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray()['access_token'];
```

Now start a session with the new $token and submit a request:

```
$session = new FacebookSession($token);
$request = new FacebookRequest(
    $session,
    'GET',
    '/'.$post_id.'/comments'
);
```

Comment: FacebookSession class is not available in Facebook SDK 5.